# Calculate the angle of a click point

Tags: c#, wpf, math

I am making a WPF control (knob). I am trying to figure out the math to calculate the angle (0 to 360) based on a mouse click position inside the circle.

For instance, if I click where the X,Y is on the image, I would have a point X,Y. I have the centerpoint as well, and cannot figure out how to get the angle.

[image: circle image]

My code below:

```
internal double GetAngleFromPoint(Point point, Point centerPoint)
{
    double dy = (point.Y - centerPoint.Y);
    double dx = (point.X - centerPoint.X);

    double theta = Math.Atan2(dy,dx);

    double angle = (theta * 180) / Math.PI;

    return angle;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got it almost right:

```
internal double GetAngleFromPoint(Point point, Point centerPoint)
{
    double dy = (point.Y - centerPoint.Y);
    double dx = (point.X - centerPoint.X);

    double theta = Math.Atan2(dy,dx);

    double angle = (90 - ((theta * 180) / Math.PI)) % 360;

    return angle;
}
```

Comment: The way I have it working is: double angle = (360 - ((theta * 180) / Math.PI)) % 360;

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. I have been googling for hours for this!

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
double theta = Math.Atan2(dx,dy);
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct calculation is this:

```
var theta = Math.Atan2(dx, -dy);
var angle = ((theta * 180 / Math.PI) + 360) % 360;
```

---

You could also let [Vector.AngleBetween](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.anglebetween.aspx) do the calculation:

```
var v1 = new Vector(dx, -dy);
var v2 = new Vector(0, 1);
var angle = (Vector.AngleBetween(v1, v2) + 360) % 360;
```

Comment: Never saw the Vector.AngleBetween. Thanks for the tip!